# Displaying an image in only its own frame with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple GUI with tkinter with buttons and images. I have a startpage with an image and buttons that take you to other pages(frames). The problem is that the image in my startpage persists and displays in the other frames.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.geometry("800x480")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        #canvas1 = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=300, bg="gray")
        #self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file="mario.png")
        #canvas1.create_image(20, 20, image=self.img)
        #canvas1.pack()

        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="mario.png")
        labelimg = tk.Label(image=photo)
        labelimg.image = photo  # keep a reference!
        labelimg.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not specified `labelimg`'s parent therefore, by default it is the main window. As a consequence, your label is packed below your container and therefore is always visible.

Changing

```
labelimg = tk.Label(image=photo)
```

into

```
labelimg = tk.Label(self, image=photo)
```

in the class `StartPage` should solve your problem.